# Using .each() to create nested Object out of table rows

Tags: javascript, html, json, object

I am desperately trying to create an `Object` while using the `.each()` loop but it doesn't seem to work. Here is the Code:

```
$("#pdfyap").on("click", function(){

    var sonarr = {};

    $("#bura tr").each(function(){
        var malzemeadi = $(this).find(".maladi").html();
        console.log(malzemeadi);
        sonarr[malzemeadi] = {};   
        sonarr[malzemeadi]["malzemekodu"] = $(this).find(".malkodu").html();
        sonarr[malzemeadi]["malzemedovizi"] = $(this).find(".doviz").html();
        sonarr[malzemeadi]["malzemekdvorani"] = $(this).find(".kdvoranbir").html();
        sonarr[malzemeadi]["malzemebirimfiyati"] = $(this).find(".birimfiyat").html();
        sonarr[malzemeadi]["malzemebirimkdvmiktari"] = $(this).find(".kdvmikbir").html();
        sonarr[malzemeadi]["malzemedovizfiyati"] = $(this).find(".dovfiyat").html();
    });
    sonarr["nettoplam"] = $("#aratop").html();
    sonarr["kdvtoplam"] = $("#kdvtop").html();
    sonarr["grosstoplam"] = $("#totaltry").html();
    console.log(sonarr);
});
```

I get all the values right but in the console the object seems to have just the key (*malzemeadi*) and the value of it is empty and  the last three ones are gotten right. long story short: just the nested ones are not being added, although the selector gets the values correct (checked it multiple times). What is it i am missing?

Here is the console log, too:

```
Object { sdfsadd: Object, fhg: Object, xcvxcv: Object, nettoplam: "6431", kdvtoplam: "245", grosstoplam: "6676" }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and it works. The problem is the console will only show the top-level items without expanding the hierarchy. Try clicking the little arrow next to the log to see the expanded hierarchy.

Alternatively, you can convert the object to JSON and log it to the console to see its hierarchy:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(sonarr, null, 4));
```

Comment: I am speechless.really. that was the only problem. everything is working but i just couldn't see it because of the reason you wrote down. thx for the hint.